Почему операции с мапой выполняются не в том порядке
Преамбула: Я в курсе, что порядок вывода элементов мапы не определен. Далее речь идет не о порядке выода элементов, а порядке выполнения функций.
Я написал методы для работы с мапой:
func (c *Cache) Save(key string, value any) {
    c.Mutex.Lock()
    defer c.Mutex.Unlock()
    _, ok := c.Storage[key]
    if ok {
        c.Error = fmt.Errorf(errs.ErrKeyAlreadyExists, key)
        return
    }
    c.Storage[key] = value
}

func (c *Cache) Get(key string) any {
    c.Mutex.Lock()
    defer c.Mutex.Unlock()
    res, ok := c.Storage[key]
    if !ok {
        return struct{}{}
    }
    return res
}

func (c *Cache) Del(key string) {
    c.Mutex.Lock()
    defer c.Mutex.Unlock()
    _, ok := c.Storage[key]
    if !ok {
        c.Error = fmt.Errorf(errs.ErrKeyIsUpset)
        return
    }
    delete(c.Storage, key)
}

Вызываются они в некотором коде уровнем повыше.
func getStoredSession(refreshToken string) (models.Session, error) {
    storedSession, ok := general.Get(cache.SessionsCache, refreshToken).(models.Session)
    if !ok {
        return models.Session{}, fmt.Errorf("%s", errs.ErrInvalidSession)
    }
    return storedSession, nil
}

func saveNewSession(newRefreshToken string, session models.Session) error {
    general.Save(cache.SessionsCache, newRefreshToken, session)
    log.Println("SAVING", cache.SessionsCache.Storage, cache.SessionsCache.Error)
    return cache.SessionsCache.Error
}

func delSession(oldRefreshToken string) error {
    general.Delete(cache.SessionsCache, oldRefreshToken)
    log.Print("delete session...", oldRefreshToken)
    return cache.SessionsCache.Error
}

Вызываются они через интерфейсные функции:
func Save(saver interfaces.SaveGeter, key string, value any) {
    saver.Save(key, value)
}

func Get(geter interfaces.SaveGeter, key string) any {
    return geter.Get(key)
}

func Delete(deleter interfaces.Deleter, key string) {
    deleter.Del(key)
}

Когда я вызываю свои api через главную страницу сайта,
Вызываю я их в определеном порядке.
Нужно сперва достать старую сессию, провести с ней работу и сгенерировать новую сессию(ключи естесственно разные), сохранить ее, удалить старую.
Вызваны в коде они ТОЧНО в указаном порядке
Но, при определенных обстоятельствах, порядок нарушается и я не могу понять почему.
Срабатвает так:
Сперва удаляет старую сессию, создает и сохраняет новую, пытается достать стару сессию(которая уже удалена)...Правильный порядок и неправильный порядок происходит в одном и том же куске кода....Я что не знаю  о каких то свойствах мапы?
Я целый день пытаюсь понять почему delete срабатывает первым. Уже просто замучался.
UPD:
Добавляю код в котором нарушется порядок выполнения. Доп инфо в комментах
func RefreshToken(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
    oldRefreshToken, err := getRefreshFromReq(r)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        encoder.Encode(&models.Repl{Error: err.Error()})
        return
    }
    serviceDescription, err := getDecriptionFromReq(r)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        encoder.Encode(&models.Repl{Error: err.Error()})
        return
    }
    // сперва нужно достать refresh сессию. Но этот фрагмент выполняется самым последним, что неожиданно.
    storedSession, err := getStoredSession(oldRefreshToken)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("ERRFETHINGSESSIONREFRESH", err, oldRefreshToken)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        encoder.Encode(&models.Repl{Error: err.Error()})
        return
    }
    service, err := getServiceByDescription(serviceDescription)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        encoder.Encode(&models.Repl{Error: err.Error()})
        return
    }
    // Неожиданное поведение.
    // delete выполняется раньше, чем getStoredSession, хотя getStoredSession выше по коду.
    // Из-за этого вся функция работает некорректно.
    // Первый refresh при логине пользователя срабатывает корректно и в правильном порядке
    // Но если удалить на сайте куку содержащую  access  токен, то порядок ломается.
    // Все параметры запросма для рефреша сессии приходят коректно.
    // Проблема только в нарушении порядка в такой ситуации.
    err = delSession(oldRefreshToken)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        encoder.Encode(&models.Repl{Error: err.Error()})
        return
    }
    secret, err := getStoredSecret(storedSession.Uid)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        encoder.Encode(&models.Repl{Error: err.Error()})
        return
    }
    refGen := refreshGen(service.Domain)
    // проверяет не истекла ли сессия
    // проверяет совпадает ли сервис из параметрах запроса с тем что лежит в refresh сессии.
    validRefSession := general.ValidToken(&refGen, storedSession)
    if !validRefSession {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        encoder.Encode(&models.Repl{Error: errs.ErrInvalidSession})
        return
    }
    general.GenToken(&refGen)
    if refGen.Error != nil {
        log.Println(refGen.Error)
        return
    }
    newSession := genNewSession(storedSession.Uname, storedSession.Uid, service)

    accGen := accessGen(service.Domain, newSession.Uname, secret)
    general.GenToken(&accGen)
    if accGen.Error != nil {
        log.Println(accGen.Error)
        return
    }
    tokens := prepareTokens(accGen.Token, refGen.Token, newSession.Uname)
    err = saveNewSession(tokens.Refresh, newSession)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        encoder.Encode(&models.Repl{Error: err.Error()})
        return
    }
    log.Println(cache.SessionsCache.Storage[tokens.Refresh], "<###")
    encoder.Encode(tokens)
}

UPD2:
Нашел проблему. Она была в логике одной из мидлварей сайта. Был пропущен else либо return и сразу выполнялся ServeHTTP().
Но остался вопрос почему выполнялось все не в том порядке

В бэкэнде сайта ваши функции, вероятно, вызываются в горутинах?

@PakUula нет, функций с горутинами написанными мной  нет вовсе. Насколько мне известно,  каждое подключение к серверу в отдельной горутине происходит(что логично).

Добавьте код где вы используете сессионные методы, возможно проблема в нём.

@DanielProtopopov Добавил код.

Не вижу возможностей для воспроизведения в вашем коде описанного сценария, к сожалению
